# Is the pivot table in google sheet will automatically removed the duplicated data when it occur at the same date or group?

Tags: google-sheets

[This is the data from my data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCWEI.png)

[This is what it show in pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m9Yt.png)

Comment: Only image is not enough to get help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.